# Arduino(ESP8266) to laravel websocket channel subscription problem

Tags: laravel, websocket, arduino, arduino-esp8266

i'm working on an IoT project which needs to connect to a laravel based socket server.
on laravel side all things are working just as should be but the problem is in arduino side which is a ESP8266 module being program by Arduino IDE.
i want to use [Links2004/arduinoWebSockets](https://github.com/Links2004/arduinoWebSockets) library to connect to server.
it connects but i can't determine on which channel it should be.
is there any way on this library to tell the channel device should be on?
I gratefully appreciate any help :)

Arduino Test Code:

```
/*
Esp8266 Websockets Client

This sketch:
    1. Connects to a WiFi network
    2. Connects to a Websockets server
    3. Sends the websockets server a message ("Hello Server")
    4. Prints all incoming messages while the connection is open

Hardware:
    For this sketch you only need an ESP8266 board.

Created 15/02/2019
By Gil Maimon
https://github.com/gilmaimon/ArduinoWebsockets

*/

#include <ArduinoWebsockets.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "****"; //Enter SSID
const char* password = "******"; //Enter Password
const char* websockets_server_host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"; //Enter server adress -- serverip_or_name
const uint16_t websockets_server_port = 6001; // Enter server port
bool connected;
 using namespace websockets;

 WebsocketsClient client;
void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
// Connect to wifi
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

// Wait some time to connect to wifi
for(int i = 0; i < 10 && WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED; i++) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(1000);
}

// Check if connected to wifi
if(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("No Wifi!");
    return;
}

Serial.println("Connected to Wifi, Connecting to server.");
// try to connect to Websockets server
 connected = client.connect(websockets_server_host, websockets_server_port, "/app/ab_key");
if(connected) {
    Serial.println("Connecetd!");
    client.send("Hello Server");
} else {
    Serial.println("Not Connected!");
}

// run callback when messages are received
client.onMessage([&](WebsocketsMessage message) {
    Serial.print("Got Message: ");
    Serial.println(message.data());
 });
}
void loop() {
 if(connected) {
    Serial.println("Connecetd!");
    client.send("Hello Server");
} else {
  connected = client.connect(websockets_server_host, websockets_server_port, "/app/ab_key");
    Serial.println("try!");
}

// let the websockets client check for incoming messages
if(client.available()) {
    client.poll();
}
delay(500);
}
```

terminal view of laravel websocket: [laravel websocket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bClzJ.png)

Comment: This would be a good question over on https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What do you mean by channel? WiFI channel or? The lib you used was very unreliable,I switched to WebSocketsServer.h which gives me more flexibility

Comment: i mean websocket channel dude by using channel 
thx

Comment: WebSocketsServer.h is it useful as client?